# What does copyWith() function do?

Tags: flutter, dart

While learning [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) from [bloclibrary](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) website, I had to use a function with the constructor named `copyWith()`. Can anyone explain to me what exactly it does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, `copyWith()` creates a clone of the object with provided parameters overridden.

Answer (score 2):

The `copywith` function creates a copy of `poststate` with some modification so that you don't need to create the whole state again.

The author said in his blog.

> "We implemented copyWith so that we can copy an instance of PostState and update zero or more properties conveniently (this will come in handy later )".

For more info, you can read the following document.

https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/docs/cs/flutterinfinitelisttutorial.md