# Flutter, riverpod StateProvider not uploading ui

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am using flutter riverpod, and I am watching a provider. But when I change the value of the provider, the build method is not being called.

The build method is not called again when I call :

```
    ref.read(customObjectProvider.notifier).state.name
```

Here is the full code

```dart
final customObjectProvider = StateProvider((ref) => MyCustomObject());

class CustomClassProviderScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CustomClassProviderScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final stateObject = ref.watch(customObjectProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Object Provider'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ref.read(customObjectProvider.notifier).state.name = 'Reuven';
              },
              child: Text('Button 1: Name')),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                ref.read(customObjectProvider.notifier).state.id = '338755093';
              },
              child: Text('Button 2: ID')),
          Text(stateObject.name ?? ''),
          Text(stateObject.id ?? ''),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomObject {
  String? name;
  String? id;

  MyCustomObject({this.name, this.id});
}
```

Comment: Can you include full widget how you are using `datePick`

Comment: More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added more code. Thanks

Comment: It is still missing `state` here, are you using consumer to read this on top level?

Comment: I made the code simplier, and its still not working. I am obviously missing something. Take a look at the new code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here StateProvider is using `MyCustomObject`, means every state will a `MyCustomObject`.

This line update the single variable(name), not the state

```
ref.read(customObjectProvider.notifier).state.name = 'Reuven';
```

You can update the state like

```dart
final MyCustomObject oldObj = ref.read(customObjectProvider);
ref.read(customObjectProvider.notifier).state =
    MyCustomObject(name: "newName"); // better will be using copyWith constructor
```

> Just updating single variable won't refresh, You need to update the state to force a refresh

More handy is by using `update`

```dart
onPressed: () {
  ref
      .read(customObjectProvider.notifier)
      .update((state) => MyCustomObject(name: "newValye"));
},
```

More about [state_provider](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_provider/).

Comment: Why are you also reading the value again? I don't need that

Comment: I just found we can use `update`, it is awesome with copywith constructor.

Comment: But I get this error with update: The method 'update' isn't defined for the type 'WidgetRef'

Comment: check if you are using the latest version `flutter_riverpod` btw it is `ref
      .read(customObjectProvider.notifier)
      .update((state) => MyCustomObject(name: "newValye"));`

Comment: Yes, it works. Why do you need to read it again. I'm watching this provider already?

Comment: It is recommended by author using read inside on `onPressed` *The watch method should not be called asynchronously, like inside an onPressed of an ElevatedButton. Nor should it be used inside initState and other State life-cycles.* You can check it [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#using-refwatch-to-observe-a-provider)