# Changes in Object from Second Screen is also Changing the Value in First Screen in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

A class Object passing from First Screen to the second Screen While on the second screen when the object changed its value, it's also changing the value on first screen.

**Code of First Screen.** (`widget.templateModel` is an object class that i am passing to the second screen)

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
EditEmojiTextTemplateScreen(templateModel: widget.templateModel,));
```

**Code of Second Screen** (On the second screen i am receiving the object and when i am changing the value of `widget.templateModel` it also changing the value on the first screen for a simple understandable code below i changed the value in initState while in the gif i am changing value in TextFormField)

```
class EditEmojiTextTemplateScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final TemplateModel templateModel;
  EditEmojiTextTemplateScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.templateModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<EditEmojiTextTemplateScreen> createState() =>
      _EditEmojiTextTemplateScreenState();
}

class _EditEmojiTextTemplateScreenState
    extends State<EditEmojiTextTemplateScreen> {
  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = sl();
  var txtNameController = TextEditingController();
  var txtColorController = TextEditingController();



  _EditEmojiTextTemplateScreenState();
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.templateModel.emoji[0].titleTwo = "kdfff"; //here i am changing the value and it also changing the value on first screen and i dont want this behavior of this object
   

    super.initState();
  }
```

[image: sample of issue]

Note: This is happening because of **widget** variable as mentioned in the documentation but i don't know how to prevent this behavior.

> package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart
>
> The current configuration.
>
> A [State] object's configuration is the corresponding [StatefulWidget]
> instance. This property is initialized by the framework before calling
> [initState]. If the parent updates this location in the tree to a new
> widget with the same [runtimeType] and [Widget.key] as the current
> configuration, the framework will update this property to refer to the
> new widget and then call [didUpdateWidget], passing the old
> configuration as an argument.

Comment: If it's the same object, why shouldn't the change in the second screen reflect on the first one?

Comment: Try to put widgetbinding.instance inside the change the object then try it

Comment: @Axel even if i create a new object and copy the value still its changing, and i dont want to make changes untill user click save button on the second screen

Comment: in first screen are you calling any consumer ?

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid  no on firstScreen data is coming through streamBuilder (snapshot.data)

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid. i try to used WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) but it did'nt worked

Comment: yes thats the problem , you updated the object in second screen and first screen you running the stream builder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251546/discussion-between-rahulvflutterandroid-and-mrazaimtiaz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see what you are trying to do.
You could initialize a NEW istance of `TemplateModel` in the `InitState` of the second screen.

Then, set the new object's properties like this (or write a cleaner method to do that):

```
newObject.property1 = oldObject.property1;
newObject.property2 = oldObject.property2;
...
```

Once the user presses the save button, change `oldObject`'s properties again, so that the first page updates.

You might want to take a look at [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) to better understand how to approach this kind of problems.

Comment: Its work by creating custom method copyWith()  but also need to use copyWith inner objects also, but still i will be look for better solution thankyou

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggests, take a look at state management solutions.
Also keep the models immutable by creating them with `final` fields. Then to modify, create new instances via [copyWith()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372580/what-is-copywith-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-flutter-and-what-are-its-use-cases)

Comment: Its work by creating custom method copyWith()  but also need to use copyWith inner objects also, but still i will be look for better solution thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Please update you code after `navigation.then` method

```
 template = snapshot.data;
```