# Flutter: Getting Error With Provider Consumer on FloatingActionButton

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

So I'm new to Flutter learning about the Provider package. I want to toggle the `bool isFavourite` and the `Icon` when the `FloatingActionButton` is pressed. But with using Provider, Consumer I'm getting an error saying:

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this
> Consumer Widget
>
> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include
> the provider of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
>
> - You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
>
> To fix, perform a hot-restart.
>
> - The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
>
>   Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route,
>   then   other routes will not be able to access that provider.
> - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
>
>   Make sure that Consumer is under your
>   MultiProvider/Provider.   This usually happens when you are
>   creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

Below is my code for `course.dart` which is Provider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Course with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double rating;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavourite;
  final bool isFeatured;

  Course({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.rating,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavourite = false,
    required this.isFeatured,
  });

  void toggleFavouriteStatus() {
    isFavourite = !isFavourite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Below is my code for `courses.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'course.dart';

class Courses with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Course> _items = [
    Course(
      id: 'c1',
      title: 'HTML & CSS',
      description: 'This is the description of HTML & CSS',
      rating: 4.5,
      imageUrl: 'http://placeimg.com/640/480/tech',
      isFeatured: true,
    ),
    Course(
      id: 'c2',
      title: 'JAVASCRIPT',
      description: 'This is the description of JAVASCRIPT',
      rating: 4.9,
      imageUrl: 'http://placeimg.com/1000/800/tech',
      isFeatured: true,
    ),
    Course(
      id: 'c3',
      title: 'WEB DEVELOPMENT',
      description: 'This is the description of WEB DEVELOPMENT',
      rating: 5,
      imageUrl: 'http://placeimg.com/640/480/tech',
      isFeatured: false,
    ),
    Course(
      id: 'c4',
      title: 'APP DEVELOPMENT',
      description: 'This is the description of APP DEVELOPMENT',
      rating: 3.8,
      imageUrl: 'http://placeimg.com/1000/800/tech',
      isFeatured: false,
    ),
    Course(
      id: 'c5',
      title: 'MACHINE LEARNING',
      description: 'This is the description of MACHINE LEARNING',
      rating: 5,
      imageUrl: 'http://placeimg.com/640/480/tech',
      isFeatured: false,
    ),
  ];

  List<Course> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  List<Course> get favouriteItems {
    return _items.where((course) => course.isFavourite).toList();
  }

  Course findById(String id) {
    return items.firstWhere((course) => course.id == id);
  }
}
```

Below is my code for `category_course_screen.dart` which is Consumer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '/providers/course.dart';

class CategoryCourseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  CategoryCourseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = '/category-course-screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Consumer<Course>(
        builder: (_, course, child) => FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(
            course.isFavourite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            course.toggleFavouriteStatus();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my code for `main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '/providers/courses.dart';
import '/screens/tabs_screen.dart';
import '/screens/enrolled_screen.dart';
import '/screens/favourites_screen.dart';
import '/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import '/screens/category_course_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => Courses(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Course App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
          primarySwatch: Colors.cyan,
          accentColor: Colors.white,
          textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                subtitle1: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontFamily: 'Lato-Bold',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
                bodyText1: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontFamily: 'Lato-Thin',
                ),
                bodyText2: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontFamily: 'Lato-Bold',
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
        ),
        // home: HomeScreen(),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => TabsScreen(),
          EnrolledScreen.routeName: (context) => EnrolledScreen(),
          FavouritesScreen.routeName: (context) => FavouritesScreen(),
          ProfileScreen.routeName: (context) => ProfileScreen(),
          CategoryCourseScreen.routeName: (context) => CategoryCourseScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your materialApp

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Added the code for MaterialApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you dont need to notify the Course class, else create a simple class like this with copyWith constructor for more benifit.

```dart
class Course {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double rating;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavourite;
  final bool isFeatured;

  Course({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.rating,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavourite = false,
    required this.isFeatured,
  });

  Course copyWith({
    String? id,
    String? title,
    String? description,
    double? rating,
    String? imageUrl,
    bool? isFavourite,
    bool? isFeatured,
  }) {
    return Course(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      title: title ?? this.title,
      description: description ?? this.description,
      rating: rating ?? this.rating,
      imageUrl: imageUrl ?? this.imageUrl,
      isFavourite: isFavourite ?? this.isFavourite,
      isFeatured: isFeatured ?? this.isFeatured,
    );
  }
}
```

Now `Courses` class will have an extra method to change the favorite option

```dart
 void toggleFavorite(String id) {
    final item = findById(id);

    _items.remove(item);
    _items.add(item.copyWith(isFavourite: !item.isFavourite));

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

And update sample cases

```dart
class CategoryCourseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryCourseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = '/category-course-screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final id = 'c1'; //example
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Consumer<Courses>(
        builder: (_, courses, child) => FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor:
              courses.findById(id).isFavourite ? Colors.pink : Colors.amber,
          onPressed: () {
            courses.toggleFavorite(id);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No. Let me rephrase it. I have another class `Courses` which is in `courses.dart`  taking care of all the `Course` models present in `course.dart`. So the issue is not the spelling I guess. It is something inside the builder method on FloatingActionButton inside the `category_course_screen.dart`

Edit: I have also added the `courses.dart` file.

Comment: You like to update specific course from `CategoryCourseScreen`?

Comment: Yes, on the basis of `course.id` the course will be marked as a favourite on pressing the `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: OK check the update one. While you are getting id it will solve your case.

Comment: thanks it solves the problem. But can you explain to me how can you do that by just adding a copyWith method and replacing the `toggleFavourite()` to `Courses` class?

Comment: if we use it on `Course` means it will affect the `Couse` not the course list.  And copyWith is a factory constructor, it clone the object & if you want to change a single field, just call the parameter. if you don't provide a filed, it will take current value. like `isFavourite: isFavourite ?? this.isFavourite,` Here is a good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62372580/10157127) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60352077/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the provider you are trying to read is in different route.
So instead of wrapping your whole MaterialApp with MultiProvider you would do something like this:

```
class CoursesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CoursesPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => Courses(),
    ),
    ],
    child: CategoryCourseScreen());
  }
}
```

Comment: I have used the `CoursesPage` as the Provider but it doesn't solve the problem (i.e. getting the same error).